# What's going on here: v5 = *(_Byte *)(this + 4)?

Tags: c++, ida

I am looking at a code dump from IDA pro.  There is a function which as this layout:

```
garbled_name(int this...
    unsigned int v5 ;
    v5 = *(_Byte *)(this + 4);
    ...
```

What I am really curious about is what exactly the '+ 4' is doing? Is this an addition or something else?

Thanks

Comment: maybe `movzx eax, byte ptr [ecx + 4]` will be easier to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code takes the integer 'this', adds 4 to it, casts it to a pointer to a byte, and then sets 'v5' to the value of the byte at that address.

Comment: You should mention that "add 4 to it" means it goes forward four times the size of the object, so if you have a class that's 1000 bytes big, it will move 4000 bytes forward.

Comment: @EboMike no, in this case it adds just 4 (it's `void this`)

Comment: Thank pkh, makes sense, still very new to this stuff and just wanted 'to be sure.'  Have a good one.

Answer (score 2):

It's just a member function of a C++ class, `this` being pointer to the object. This signature of the object is probably:

```
class some_class {
    int i;    // int, void*, short, anything with sizeof() <= 4, and it's not char. 
              // It also can be absent if it's a virtual class (AFAIK it's compiler dependend)
    unsigned char c; // or c[N]
    ...
};
```

The code in question is:

```
some_class::some_fn(...){
    unsigned int v5 = c; // or c[0]
    ...
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a reference to the fifth byte from the beginning of the object.  Depending on what compiler generated that code, it is most likely the item in class order which is at the fifth byte in the object instance.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Sigh, I missed the "IDA Pro" part. I'll just leave this here for entertainment value, in case someone is wondering what "this+4" does in normal C++ code.

<strike>"this+4" takes your current this pointer, moves forward four times its size. Then it casts that to a byte pointer and reads it.</strike>

Consider this:

```
struct A {
    void foo();

    int x;
    int y;
};
```

sizeof(A), on a 32-bit system, is most likely 8 bytes.

```
A myArray[8];
A *pA = myArray;
```

Now pA points to &myArray[0].

```
pA++;
```

Now pA points to &myArray[1], i.e. it moved 8 bytes forward.

```
void A::foo() {
    A *pA = this + 4;
}
```

If you call this on &myArray[0], it will point to &myArray[4], i.e. 32 bytes further down the road.